# UImagview Fading and then hiding

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I want the imageview to fade and then hide completely.

Here is my code

```
   CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
   theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
   theAnimation.duration=1.0;
   theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
   theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   [flowerImageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

This is working properly but when the value becomes 0.0 the imageview should not appear again

Comment: After it fades out. You just remove it from superview (which is UIImageView). [imageView removeFromSuperview].

Comment: but how will I come to know that the value became 0

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11487269/1328096 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no callback method for this so set the `NSTimer`

```
     CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
     theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
     theAnimation.duration=1.0;
     theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
     theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
     [flowerImageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theAnimation.duration
        target:self
        selector:@selector(targetMethod)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:NO];
```

following method called after animation completed

```
-(void)targetMethod
{
     flowerImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pratik is on right way but image will be there just it wont be shown to you.

You can try following solution too, it will completely hide image.

```
 CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
 theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
 theAnimation.duration=1.0;
 theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
 theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
 [flowerImageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theAnimation.duration
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

Then hide image completely after animation completes.

```
-(void)targetMethod
{
     [flowerImageView setHidden:YES];
}
```