# Fade In UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am able to fade out my image successfully. When I try to fade it back in, it does not "fade" in... it just comes back abruptly. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code for fading it out and for trying to fade it back in:

Fading it out:

```
//Fade Out
Image.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^ {Image.alpha = 0;}
completion:^(BOOL finished){Image.hidden = YES;}];
```

This is what I use for trying to fading it back in; basically, I am doing the opposite... why doesn't it work?

```
//Fade In
Image.hidden = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^ {Image.alpha = 1;}
completion:^(BOOL finished){Image.hidden = NO;}];
```

Comment: I would use the `UIView.transtion` method instead--easier and has more options. Works from null image, or from image -> image. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9773674/111243

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image needs to be visible all the time while you're fading it in.  You are animating the alpha property on a hidden image, and then showing it at the end.  Correct would be:

```
Image.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:1.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                 animations:^{ Image.alpha = 1; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You hide it first, so the fading is invisible. You need to set the alpha to 0 instead.

```
image.alpha = 0.0;
image.hidden = NO;
// do the animation to alpha => 1.0;
```

BTW, you should not use capitalized variable names.

Comment: and set image.alpha =1.0 for Fade Out before starting animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is I think the shortest way of doing it. Create a UIView animation and commit it on your imageView.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[myImageView setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```