# It's possible to add a dissolve transition when changing images in a UIImageView, but what about when you initially add it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

Say I'm adding a UIImageView, and I want to dissolve it in so instead of appearing sharply it's a little more smooth to show up. Is this possible?

As outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773674/998117) answer, you can dissolve changes as so:

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myname.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:5.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                  self.imageView.image = toImage;
                } completion:nil];
```

Just curious if additions can receive similar treatment.

Comment: You could easily answer this yourself with a little experimentation. So, try it and see what happens.

Comment: I did. It didn't work.

Comment: Hmmm.... it did when I tried it. I dragged an image view into the canvas, and gave it constraints (left,top,width,height), then added the code you posted to a button method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your code will do what you want,Just have a try with the code below:
(Btw: don't call transitionWithView: in viewDidLoad:,animation for imageView not work in viewDidLoad)

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

ViewController.m
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage * imageOne;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage * imageTwo;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
  self.imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.jpg"];
  [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //init imageView here
    if(self.imageView.image == nil){
        [self performSelector:@selector(handleButtonTouch:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}

- (IBAction)handleButtonTouch:(id)sender {

  UIImage * toImage = ([self.imageView.image isEqual:self.imageOne]) ? self.imageTwo : self.imageOne;

  [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                    duration:3.0f
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                  animations:^{
                    self.imageView.image = toImage;
                  }
                  completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a completely blank image initially, and then change it to the image of your choice - that will give you the "dissolve animation on addition" feel you want.