# transitionWithView not working for swapping UIImage from UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, objective-c-blocks

Base on what I've read in the replies to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638831/fade-dissolve-when-changing-uiimageviews-image) the following should work:

```
UIImageView *snapshotView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];

[self.container.view addSubview:snapshotView];


for(int i = 1;i < 5; i = i +1){

        UIImage *snapshotImage = [self blurredInboxBgImageWithRadius: (i * 5)];
        [UIView transitionWithView:snapshotView
                      duration:2.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                        snapshotView.image = snapshotImage;
                    } completion:nil];
    }
```

But it doesn't. It does not animate the image changes at all. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to initiate the next transition in the completion block of the previous transition to have them happen sequentially.

Comment: That makes sense - but why does the change happen instantly rather than taking two seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to initiate the next transition in the completion block of the previous transition to have them happen sequentially.
2. You need to use the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` option, not `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`

Here's some code I mocked up to do a sequence of transitions on a label:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger iterationCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation ViewController

// called on button tap
- (IBAction)startTransitioning:(id)sender {
    self.iterationCount = 0;
    [self iterateTransition];
}

- (void)iterateTransition
{
    if (self.iterationCount < 5) {
        self.iterationCount++;
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.label duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.iterationCount];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self iterateTransition];
        }];
    } else {
        self.iterationCount = 0;
    }
}

@end
```