# Handle iOS animation

Tags: ios, xcode

I simply want the .png to stay after this animation. It successfully shows the first image, then transitions to the next, however after a duration of 6 seconds, it disappears.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"newblue.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackbox.png"],
                         nil];
UIImageView *animationView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
animationView.animationDuration=6.5;
animationView.animationRepeatCount=1;
[animationView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:animationView];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fade/dissolve when changing UIImageView's image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638831/fade-dissolve-when-changing-uiimageviews-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `image` property of the `UIImageView` to the image you want to persist on screen.

```
animationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackbox.png"];
```