# How to change UIImageView with some Transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am making an image editor application.

I am able to change the `UIImage` of a `UIImageView` but I want it to be more efficient and beautiful.

Currently I am changing `UIImage` as

```
if(image)
  {
     userImageView.image = image;
  }
```

It directly changes the `UIImage`. How can I make a `fadeIn-fadeOut` effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 [UIView transitionWithView:YourUIImageView
                              duration:2.0f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{
                                YourUIImageView.image = image;
                            } completion:nil];
```

And Do some googling before asking this question already has and answer.

[Check THIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638831/fade-dissolve-when-changing-uiimageviews-image)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.fadeDuration=1;
}
return self;
}
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)newImage{

if(!self.image||self.fadeDuration<=0){
    super.image=newImage;
} else {
    UIImageView *iv=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    iv.contentMode=self.contentMode;
    iv.image=super.image;
    iv.alpha=1;
    [self addSubview:iv];
    super.image=newImage;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:self.fadeDuration delay:0       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        iv.alpha=0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [iv removeFromSuperview];
    }];
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
-(void)fade{

    //fade out
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        [userImageView setAlpha:0.0f];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //fade in
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            userImageView.image = image;
            [userImageView setAlpha:1.0f];

        } completion:nil];

    }];
}
```