# UIImageView fade between animation

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, ios-animations

I need to animate between images in a UIImageView. So after research I came out with this class:

```
    import UIKit

    class GzImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageCollection:[UIImage]? //images to show
    var count:Int = 0 // images counter

    func animate(){
        //when Counter get last image set it to the first one
        if self.count >= self.imageCollection?.count {
            self.count = 0
        }
        //get the image to show
        let img = self.imageCollection![self.count]
        //animate the transition
        UIView.transitionWithView(self,
            duration: 1.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: { self.image = img }) //set the new image
            { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.animate() //Direct recursion
            self.count++
        }
    }                     
 }
```

And I use it that way:

```
let imgView = GzImageView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 200, 200))
imgView.imageCollection = ["cake.png","bag.png","hat.png"].map { name -> UIImage in UIImage(named:name)!}
imgView.animate()
```

It works fine when I use as an UIView subview. But I need to use this as a UICollectionViewCell subview. And as a UICollectionViewCell subview it doesn't work properly. When I change to other UIView and came back to UICollectionView images start to blink very fast.

I couldn't figure out the problem, so I'm looking for another way to get this functionality.

Do you guys have another way to do that or know how to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 3.0.1 try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710002/4935811:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.imageView,
          duration:0.5,
          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
          animations: { self.imageView.image = newImage },
          completion: nil)
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/licvido/bc22343cacfa3a8ccf88

Answer (score -2):

You can do it easily in this way:

```
var animationDuration = 3;

            imageView.animationImages = imageSet;
            imageView.animationDuration = NSTimeInterval(animationDuration);
            imageView.startAnimating();
```

here imageSet in array of UIImage objects.

Comment: It works fine, but this code doesn't have the fade effect between the animations. Do you know to add this effect in this implementation ?