# How to achieve animations when changing image in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an **NSArray *pictureRefs** which contains names of pictures.

These pictures are to be displayed in UIImageView **_mainImage**
Which works fine so far.
At the moment I´m using the buttons on the left and right to do so, see picture below. The buttons have tags which correspond with **pictureRefs**.

The change takes place very straight without any effects.
I would like to implement coverflow like animations.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

**My code to switch image**

```
string =  [pictureRefs objectAtIndex:tag];
UIImage  *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:string];
[_mainImage setImage:image]; //Here I would like to make animations
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834693/1990236 this should help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638831/fade-dissolve-when-changing-uiimageviews-image/38350024#38350024

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate the change of image in an UIImageView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834573/how-to-animate-the-change-of-image-in-an-uiimageview)

Answer (score 2):

call this method when clicked on any button

```
-(void)check_changeImage:(NSInteger)Value
{
    NSString *strimagename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice_0%d.png",Value];//fetch image here as per you want 

 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                 animations:^{
                     imgviewDice1.image.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     imgviewDice1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:strimagename];

                     // do something after the animation finished, 
                     // maybe releasing imageA if it's not used anymore...
                 }];

}
```

may be it will help.