# Xamarin iOS: How to fade in an image using SDWebImage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm using `Xamarin.SDWebImage` 4.4.7 from Microsoft and would like to fade in an image. I know that the original library has [built-in image transitions](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/Advanced-Usage#image-transition-430):

```
imageView.sd_imageTransition = .fade
let url = URL(string: "https://foo/bar.jpg")
imageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
```

How can this be done in Xamarin?

Comment: What does your xamarin.ios code look like currently?

Comment: Nothing special. I'm using the `SetImage` extension method from SDWebImage and passing an `NSUrl`. Here's an example: `uiImageView.SetImage(new NSUrl(source))`

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at github source for that nuget, [SDWebImage/ApiDefinition.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/blob/main/iOS/SDWebImage/source/SDWebImage/ApiDefinition.cs) only mentions image download & caching APIs of SDWebImage. Looking at original lib demo's [MasterViewController](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Examples/SDWebImage%20Demo/MasterViewController.m), library uses a customImageView to do transitions. AFAIK, No easy way to add to xamarin version. Use [iOS CoreAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077671/199364) for transitions.