# add subview with animation

Tags: iphone, animation

Can anybody help me with adding subview with animation. I want add subview with animation like  CATransition, but with this class we have only several different animation type. But i looking for ability implement it's own animation - different part of view appearing in different time.

Maybe there is exists some examples or something else

Comment: You mean you want something other than CATransition animations? Do you have a sample of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement this code for add subview with animation

```
 new_view.hidden=NO;

    CATransition *transition=[CATransition animation];
    transition.type=kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromTop;
    transition.duration=0.10;
    [[new_view layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"animation2"];
```

Answer (score 1):

for UIView Animations:

```
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is OFF screen!
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is ON screen!
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

There are also build in animations as flip and curl:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:newView
                            cache:YES];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:settingsView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337408/addsubview-animation) some more: