# How to add a subview with a presentmodalview type animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I need to

> add a subview to a view  with presentmodalview type animation

But in

> CATransition

I didn't find any type of transition like that. Also in

> UItransitionstyle

Can anybody guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use CATransition

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
[animation setDuration:0.6f];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[subview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"someTransition"];
```

Comment: can u pls tell me also how i can remove this by the same animation of dismissmodalviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yoursubview];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[animation setDuration:1.00];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[yoursubview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeTransition"];
```

For more info check these links

1. [Code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alanjrogers/671918)
2. [Implement Changes Between Two Views In iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-changes-between-two-views-in-iphone/)
3. [add subview with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571653/add-subview-with-animation?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Change the frame of the subview insite the `UIView` Animation, like as follows,

initially set the

```
subView.frame=CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height,your_width,your_height);
```

then set the required frame position inside the animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^ {

        // set subView's frame

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }
     ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `UIView` animation block:

```
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yourSuperView.frame.size.height, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);
[yourSuperView addSubview:yourView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Task to do on Animation completion.
}];
```

You change the animation duration according to your convince. Also you can use following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations: {
      //your Implemntation
}];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    
}];
```

Please check the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for animation option in `UIViewAnimationOptions` section and detail of methods.