# Animated view transitions in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, interface-builder

I have an iPhone app which has a menu. Each menu item will take you to another page. I would like to know how to perform simple animations page transitions (fade in/out, slide). Is this possible within interface builder or do I need different software?

Comment: your question text is different from the title...

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337408/addsubview-animation)

Comment: Yes, yes, hot dog, hot dog, yes sir, no sir, maybe ok. Did that make sense to you? Please change the question title.

Comment: yea you decided to get a hot dog and....tw@

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anyhow, we can do this programmatically.

Pl. look at this [a link](http://sree.cc/iphone/adding-transition-effects-flip-horizontal-and-page-curl)

Comment: The code at that link contains multiple errors and omissions.  It was clearly never tested at all; ignore it.  Instead see the post linked to in the comments above, or perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice).