# Viewdid load method call on popview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, popviewcontroller

In my application i set some animations in View1's view load() ,At first launch its working propely,if im pushed into otherview ,and while pop into view1 its not animating,What shoud i do for animate while pop view from other view?here my view did load code,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
artext=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arimage=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arsound=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[super viewDidLoad];
[self copysqlitetodocuments];
[self Readthesqlitefile];   
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"classroom.png"]];

}
```

i tried with

```
  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
 [self buttonmover];
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  }
```

its not working,Can any one pls help me to solve this problem

Comment: my buttonmover function gives animation,i tried it with view didappear its shows oly in first launch,Wen i pop from other view its not showing the animation? @vishy

Comment: show us the button mover function, hw u r performing animations..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute code when the view appears (e.g. an animation), `-viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to do it.

You should probably use:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Or viewWillAppear it sometimes makes the loading look a bit smoother

Answer (score 0):

Try in viewWillAppear

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
  artext=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  arimage=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  arsound=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [self copysqlitetodocuments];
  [self Readthesqlitefile];   
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"classroom.png"]];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When your viewDidLoad method is called, the controller isn't yet in the view hierarchy, so the animations doesn't work.

You have to perform animations in **viewWillApper**, after implementing the method **[super viewWillAppear]**. Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    artext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arimage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arsound = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self copysqlitetodocuments];
    [self Readthesqlitefile];   
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"classroom.png"]];

}
```

Comment: whether while back pop from other view it will show the animations huh?

Comment: So you need an animation only the first time?

Comment: So this code should give you a good example to how to implement that ;-)

Comment: depends on your animation. You asked for a function that animates every time, not about the animation itself. Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337408/addsubview-animation