# setAnimationTransition apparently being ignored

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have a button with an `IBAction` which is supposed to display a `subview`. The `view` is in the storyboard and I'm calling it was `instantiateViewController`. This works fine. I would like to animate the views transition onto the screen which is where I hit this problem. The following code is what I have however all it does is display the entire `view` at once but without text on buttons etc. and then drags the text down from the top. Quite obscure. Commenting out the `setAnimationTransition` line heralds the same result.

```
MapViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:MapViewController.view cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:MapViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

As per the comment below I have changed it to:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{[self.view addSubview:MapViewController.view];} completion:NULL];
```

However the problem still persists.

Comment: [Remember these:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)
_Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead._

Comment: Ok, so I changed it to: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{[self.view addSubview:MapViewController.view];} completion:NULL]; however I still have the same problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Animated the adding of a scene to a custom container (in which case you need containment calls, `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`). Or are you trying to transition to another scene, in which case you should either `presentViewController` or `pushViewController`). We can't help you on your animation until we understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Adam look at this question, exactly the same wanted behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561946/342437 . The answer by adedoy is the one you are after.

Comment: @mbogh Thanks! Unbelievably I tried that one earlier and found it not to work. I must have done something different this time as it now works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView duration:0.5
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp //change to whatever animation you like
    animations:^ { [containerView addSubview:subview]; }
    completion:nil];
```

Seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                duration:0.5
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                   [self.view addSubview:MapViewController.view];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:MapViewController.view 
                         cache:YES];
```

to

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:self.view 
                         cache:YES];
```

You are not animating the view you add, you animate the container...

Also note that this set of methods is deprecated and if you are not targetting iOS < 4.0, you should use the block-based animation methods instead.

Don't use `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight`, that's only for the block-based methods (see Akash's answer).